# Django formModel's fields conflict

Tags: python, django

I have two models and two modelForms:

```
class Email(models.Model):
    # ....
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)


class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
     # ....
     is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

class EmailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ['email', 'email_type', 'is_main']

class PhoneNumberForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PhoneNumber
        fields = ['phone_number', 'phone_number_type', 'is_main']
```

Also i have a template:

```
<form>
    {{ email_form }}
    {{ number_form }}
</form>
```

Django rendering a template with two the same id's and label's for field `is_main`. And they conflict to each other. How i can fix it without renaming `is_main`?

Comment: Use a [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms).

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you. It works.